# Why Jenkins builds stops working by schedule?

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos, continuous-integration, devops

I was configure my build by schedule `*/5 * * * *` - every 5 min.
Works great. But after some time jenkins stops start build.
Log does not have any information about this

After restart jenkins, build starts by schedule, but after some time problem was back. Here is memory usage screenshot
[image: a busy cat]

OS - CentOS;
4GB RAM;
`JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx3000m -Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Who have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Check the messages in garbage collector log.

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce the garbage collection & heap memory allocation, looks like system consuming all the memory. Try to reduce JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx3000m to JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1500m and test and run. it will work for you.